# c# запись и чтение в бинарный файл

Tags: c#, файловая-система, binary

Было дано задание:

> Данные должны храниться в бинарном файле следующего формата:
> [Сигнатура][Запись с id 1][Запись с id 2]…[Запись с id N]
>
> Сигнатура
> файла – первые 8 букв ваших фамилии, имени и отчества на латинице.
> Сигнатура файла – первые 8 букв ваших фамилии, имени и отчества на
> латинице.
>
> Запись должна содержать:
>
> Флаг удаления (1 байт): 0 для существующих записей и 1 для удаленных
>
> Тип записи (1 байт): номер варианта вашей записи
>
> Данные ваших записей (длина – максимальный размер из ваших вариантов
> записей)
>
> Данные формируются из полей вашей записи:
>
> Поле типа int – 4 байта
>
> Поле типа string – фиксированный размер строки с завершающим нулем
> (например, 100 байт
>
> Поле типа bool – 1 байт

Как правильно установить фиксированный размер на запись строки? Например как в задании. Допустим я захочу записать строку которая будет занимать 20 символов, то как ограничить фиксированный размер строки в 100 байт? Заполнять пробелами пока не будет заполнено все 100 байт? Можно ли это сделать как то другим способом? Не очень понимаю как это реализовать.

А так же как например реализовать поиск по бинарному файлу. Допусти мне нужно найти строку c id 20.
Просто идти в лоб?
Запустить цикл и перебирать подходящий id?
Если так,то какой цикл использовать? foreach в таком случаем не подойдет ибо он будет итерировать только по 1 символу.
Помогите пожалуйста разобраться как правильно реализовать это задание

моя запись файла на данный момент выглядит так:

```
public TravelRouteV13 Save(TravelRouteV13 records) {
  var parsedDate1 = DateTime.Parse(records.data_1);
  var parsedDate2 = DateTime.Parse(records.data_2);
  BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(pathFromData, FileMode.Append));
    record.Add(records);
    writer.Write($"[id:{records.id},address:{records.address},activity:{records.activity},data:{parsedDate2.Subtract(parsedDate1)},delete:{0}],");
    writer.Close();
    return records;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

берем строчку, например

```cs
string text = "Hello world";
```

Преобразуем ее в массив байт используя кодировку например UTF-8

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
```

Делаем длину массива 100 байт

```cs
if (bytes.Length != 100)
    Array.Resize(ref bytes, 100);
```

Как записать массив байт с помощью `BinaryWriter` вы уже знаете.

Потом обратно

```
int eol = Array.IndexOf(bytes, 0);
if (eol > 0)
    Array.Resize(ref bytes, eol);
string result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

*Русские буквы кодируются 2 байтами, поэтому 100 байт != 100 символов.*

Comment: все понял, спасибо!

Comment: Я бы UTF-8 не использовал, максимальный размер символа UTF-8 = 3 байта. Я бы использовал bool isNotNull + char[48] + '\0' для таких жёстких ограничений, если мы делаем свой формат хранения. Если предполагается, что будет только RU+ENG, и необходимо надёжно 98 символов - можно использовать Windows-1251. Либо если всё-же UTF-8 - надо как-то проверять за пределы одного байта не выходило.

Comment: @Blackmeser задание так себе, z-string нулём обрезается, а не фиксируется. А кодировка не имеет значения.